# Using wildcard pattern for a function with default parameter value throws compiler 254 error

Tags: swift

The documentation says that you can ask Swift not to use the default parameter name as the external parameter using the wildcard `_`:

```
func hello(_ str:String = "Hello with wildcard pattern") {
  println(str)
}

hello("this is my string")
```

But I get a `254` trying to compile it:

> failed with exit code 254 (tested on Xcode 6 beta1 and beta2)

but obviously it works fine when I call it with no arguments.

and then when I do: `hello(str: "this is my string")`, it says that `str` is "extraneous"

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a quick workaround you can get it to work by adding another parameter to your function, like this:

```
func hello(extra: Int, _ str: String = "Hello with wildcard pattern") {
    println(str)
}

hello(0, "hello")
```

The 254 error is coming from the compiler, so I'd file a bug report with Apple. Even if isn't valid code, the compiler should not crash, but from what I've read, your code should work.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a compiler bug. You can use overloads to mimic the behaviour for now.